# Piloting Microsoft Word With Ole in C++ Builder : how to put Word in the foreground

Tags: c++, ms-word, c++builder, ole

I've got a code (which works fine) for piloting word with C++ Builder.
It's useful for reaching different bookmarks in the document.

```
Variant vNom, vWDocuments, vWDocument, vMSWord, vSignets, vSignet;
    vNom = WideString("blabla.doc");
    try
    {
        vMSWord = Variant::GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        vMSWord = Variant::CreateObject("Word.Application");
    }
    vMSWord.OlePropertySet("Visible", true);
    vWDocuments = vMSWord.OlePropertyGet("Documents");
    vWDocument = vWDocuments.OleFunction("Open", vNom);
    vSignets = vWDocument.OlePropertyGet("BookMarks");
    if (vSignets.OleFunction("Exists", signet))
    {
        vSignet = vSignets.OleFunction("Item", signet);
        vSignet.OleFunction("Select");
    }
```

But once the document is opened, the user can no longer see when an other bookmark has been reached, since the application stays in background.

Does anyone know how i can do to make Word displayed in the foreground, or to light-up the document in the taskbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple trick to do that (using Win32 API):

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
```

You must find the hwnd of word using the [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "FindWindow" method:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL,"blabla.doc - Microsoft Word");
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
```